# How to publish Azure Web App on a slow internet connection?

Tags: azure, web-deployment

My internet connection speed is extremely slow (< 3 MBps). When I publish on Azure App Service from Visual Studio, it keeps timing out halfway. I find I am only able to publish when my connection speed is > 5 Mbps. Is there a way to publish to Azure on very slow connection?

Comment: Try to zip-deploy directly to Kudos, here's a link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/12/28/deploy-to-an-azure-app-service-using-kudu-and-a-zip-file/

Comment: Hello, I want to check if you have solved your issue now. If the post is helpful, can you please help accept it as answer? And if you have more issues, please let me know:).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a try of zip deploy as mentioned in the comment.

Here is the official link of [zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip). You can [deploy it via UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file) by nav to this site: `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI`, or [Deploy ZIP file with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file-with-azure-cli)